# .Net library/ORM that returns structured (strongly typed) data from MySQL query?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, orm

I try to extract data from a MySQL query using MySQLCommand command object and call the `ExecuteReader()` method. What I get back is sometimes very time-consuming to parse. For example I like to get the names as string of all the tables that a database holds.

using the following I am not sure how to parse to a collection of strings:

```
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SHOW TABLES", connection);
        var result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Is there a library or ORM that returns results in a more .Net way? For instance returning data as .Net collections...

Comment: Look at NHibernate. It supports MySql

Comment: @IlyaIvanov, will take a look, thanks for the suggestion. Would NHibernate or for that matter any ORM actually solve what I tried to explain in my question? Would such library return a collection of strings for my above sql command?

Comment: Well, not quite. You also probably want to look at Massive https://github.com/robconery/massive dynamic ORM, which mapps result to dynamic. You then can access `result[0].Name`

Comment: Forget NHIbernate, it's a beast. Go for a micro ORM. See PetaPoco  (http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) or SqlFu (https://github.com/sapiens/SqlFu) or OrmLite (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)

Comment: thanks I will equally take a look at your suggested ORMs as well, thanks for pointing out.